# What is the correct event to watch for if you want to know when a Metro app is closing?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I know that in Desktop apps we have things like `Form_Closing` which is great for doing stuff before the app shuts down, but I need to do things before a Metro app shuts down (is closed by the user or the system) and I can't get this working.

The only events that seem to be even remotely related are the `App_Suspending` and `pageRoot_Unloaded` events.

My problem is that my code (any code at all) never gets called if I put it in the Unloaded event, which makes me believe that the Unloaded event never gets fired.

I haven't tried using the Suspending event yet because I need to do this work when the app is actually closing, or about to be closed, not just suspended.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can override OnNavigatedFrom method which will be invokved when page is being navigated away from.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedfrom.aspx

I dont think there is any explicit calls for app being terminated (accept checking the previous state in app.xaml.cs)

Answer (score 3):

There is no diff between Closing and Suspending Metro App on the moment of suspending, so you must save state in OnSuspending override every time. But after re-Activating you can see what was happened with your App (OnLaunched (for example, here you can see value ClosedByUser)).
[Here](http://iinspectable.wordpress.com/2012/07/08/forcing-metro-apps-to-terminate/) is not bad article about WinRT LifeCycle.